# Html form to text file

Tags: php, html, forms

On my website i got a form looks like this on index.html:

```
<form id="demo" action='submit.php' method='post' enctype='text/plain'>
link: <input type='text' name='web'></br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

And then in the submit.php i got:

```
<?php
$fp=fopen('sub.txt','a'); 
fwrite($fp,addslashes($web)); 
fclose($fp); 
header('location: thanks.html'); 
exit();
?>
```

But when i press submit the result in sub.php is beeing

```
/n
```

But it should be

```
example.com/n
```

What is wrong in the php code.

I want the link submited in the form printed in the file sub.txt and then the person be redirected to a thank you page.

Comment: Shouldn't `$web` be `$_POST['web']`?

Comment: Do you mean fwrite($fp,addslashes($_POST['web'])); ? @j08691

Comment: where you have set `$web`? is your `register globals` on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing `value` attribute  as well as you need `$_POST` to get the value inside sub.php

```
<form id="demo" action='submit.php' method='post' enctype='text/plain'>
link: <input type='text' name='web' value="" /></br>
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>

<?php
$fp=fopen('sub.txt','a'); 
fwrite($fp,addslashes($_POST['web']). "\r\n"); 
fclose($fp); 
header('location: thanks.html'); 
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Please note that the `value` attribute is not required, [as stated in the W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search)) : "The value attribute, __if specified__ [...]"

Comment: Working almost correctly. But it's 1 problem: (sub.txt) submision 1 was hello.com and submission 2 was Bye the result is: hello.comBye how to add commas or spaces?

Comment: Thank you. You can check the result at http://bitcointips.bugs3.com/beta in one minuit.